# How to add a new recipe in yocto?

Tags: embedded-linux, libraries, yocto, recipe

I am trying to add a new recipe to install new packages in my image. I need the next packages libnfc5 libnfc-bin libnfc-examples, I have found these packages in this page: http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnfc/, so I am using the next commands to install the packages:

- devtool add libnfc5 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnfc/libnfc5_1.7.1-4+b1_armhf.deb
- devtool build libnfc5
- devtool deploy-target libnfc5 root@my-ip

I am not sure if is necessary modify the .bb file generate: libnfc5_1.7.1-4+b1.bb, and one time that I execute deploy-target which is necessary to do in my device, Do I need to install the library?

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@lokeshsharma596/yocto-lab-02-creating-custom-layer-and-writing-recipe-for-hello-world-f4438311bbfc

this is a very good article on recipe.

Answer (score 1):

`libnfc` is already exist in `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-core/libnfc`.

Make sure `meta-oe` is in your `bblayers.conf` and `bitbake` it.

Then, you can deploy it with `devtool deploy-target`.

Also, for `nfc` test tool you can check this github project [pcsc-tools](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pcsc-tools).

Here is a recipe if you want to integrate it to your image:

- **meta-custom/recipes-tools/pcsc/pcsc_git.bb**

```
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENCE;md5=94d55d512a9ba36caa9b7df079bae19f"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/LudovicRousseau/pcsc-tools;protocol=https"

PV = "1.5.7+git${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "691ae06a6925b7a0e283016c8a05725959beebb3"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

DEPENDS = "pcsc-lite"

inherit pkgconfig autotools
```

You can then add it to your image:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " pcsc"
```

or, you can deploy it using `devtool` as well.

Comment: Why in the case of pcsc is not necessary in the bb file do_install or do_compile? Thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: Tasks are handled in `autotools` and `pkgconfig` classes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I have other problem with the git repositories and devtool, if I use devtool add and the master branch work fine the command, for example: devtool add libtest https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc. But if I select a tag don't work devtool, for example: devtool add libtest https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/tree/libnfc-1.7.1. This error is shown: ERROR: Command 'script -e -q -c "recipetool --color=always create --devtool -o /tmp/devtoolumvxr22c 'https://github.com/nfc-tools/libnfc/tree/libnfc-1.7.1'  - ... What is happened? How can I solved it?